# iOS programming. How to get picture from the phone for a phonebook app

Tags: ios

I need your help/references/hints on how to get a pictures from 1) my Gallery in iPhone and 2)from the iPhone front camera. So that my program copies this picture to its local folder on iPhone (not just referencing to Gallery). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might find the info on [this appple developer doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) useful. You use UIImagePickerController to present a modal view, as shown in the code below, from the doc above.

```
- (BOOL) startMediaBrowserFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
           usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                               UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate {

if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
             UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum] == NO)
        || (delegate == nil)
        || (controller == nil))
    return NO;

UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

// Displays saved pictures and movies, if both are available, from the
// Camera Roll album.
mediaUI.mediaTypes =
    [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];

// Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
// trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
mediaUI.allowsEditing = NO;

mediaUI.delegate = delegate;

[controller presentModalViewController: mediaUI animated: YES];
return YES;                          
}
```

I do suggest you read through the doc above, as it is very informative but not easily paraphrasable.

Hope this helps!